# TypeError: (...).draw is not a function while trying to filter a datatable

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm trying to create a datatable that can be filtered by a data range. It's working basically everything, except for that it throws an exception when trying to update the table after changing the date fields. Here's my code:

**tablas.js**:

```
tablaTransacciones  = $('#tabla-transacciones');

$(document).ready( function () {
    tablaTransacciones.DataTable({
        "dom": '<"top"i>frt<"bottom">p<"clear">',
        "info":     false,
        "ordering": true, 
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
        "lengthChange": false,
        "pageLength": 4,
        "fixedHeader": true,
        "language": {
            "searchPlaceholder": "Buscar registro",
            "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
            "sSearch":         "",
            "sUrl":            "",
            "sInfoThousands":  ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst":    "Primero",
                "sLast":     "Último",
                "sNext":     '<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>',
                "sPrevious": '<i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>',
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        },
    });

    yadcf.init(tablaTransacciones, [{
        column_number: 0
    }]);
});

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min  = $('#min-date').val()
        var max  = $('#max-date').val()
        var createdAt = data[0] || 0;
        var diffDate = moment(createdAt);
        min = moment(min).subtract('1','days');
        max = moment(max).add('1','days');
        if (
        (min == "" || max == "") ||
        (diffDate.isBetween(min, max))


        ) {  return true;  }
        return false;

    }
);

$('#min-date').change(function() {
    tablaTransacciones.draw();
});

$('#max-date').change(function() {
    tablaTransacciones.draw();
});
```

When I click and change the date, I do indeed get the event dispatched, but console throws the following error:

> TypeError: tablaTransacciones.draw is not a function[Aprender más]
>   tablas.js:69:5

If I type something on the default filter, I do indeed get the filtered table I want.

Any idea on what's going on here?

EDIT: I'm using a date input instead of a plain text input on the html. That's why I'm relying on the change event.

Comment: tablaTransacciones is a JQuery object, not the reference to the DataTables object. So "draw" probably does not exist. When you establish the datatable, capture the result. For example var myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable(); -- now myTable.draw() exists.

Comment: Oh, my! Thank you! Doing so worked. Had to move the params to the new definition of the datatable so it could draw as intended again, but it worked flawlessly. Thank you!!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help. I made my comment an answer. If you could take the time to mark it as the answer, I'd appreciate it! Happy coding.

Comment: Done already! Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tablaTransacciones is a JQuery object, not the reference to the DataTables object. So "draw" probably does not exist. When you establish the datatable, capture the result. For example

```
var myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();
```

-- now myTable.draw() exists.

Here is an example of your code where I create a separate object for DataTables called "tablaTransacciones_dt." This object is used to redraw the table after a change is made.

```
tablaTransacciones  = $('#tabla-transacciones');

tablaTransacciones_dt = null;

$(document).ready( function () {
    tablaTransacciones_dt = tablaTransacciones.DataTable({
        "dom": '<"top"i>frt<"bottom">p<"clear">',
        "info":     false,
        "ordering": true, 
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
        "lengthChange": false,
        "pageLength": 4,
        "fixedHeader": true,
        "language": {
            "searchPlaceholder": "Buscar registro",
            "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
            "sSearch":         "",
            "sUrl":            "",
            "sInfoThousands":  ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst":    "Primero",
                "sLast":     "Último",
                "sNext":     '<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>',
                "sPrevious": '<i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>',
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        },
    });

    yadcf.init(tablaTransacciones, [{
        column_number: 0
    }]);
});

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min  = $('#min-date').val()
        var max  = $('#max-date').val()
        var createdAt = data[0] || 0;
        var diffDate = moment(createdAt);
        min = moment(min).subtract('1','days');
        max = moment(max).add('1','days');
        if (
        (min == "" || max == "") ||
        (diffDate.isBetween(min, max))


        ) {  return true;  }
        return false;

    }
);

$('#min-date').change(function() {
    tablaTransacciones_dt.draw();
});

$('#max-date').change(function() {
    tablaTransacciones_dt.draw();
});
```